# Changing tabbar active index from another widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a TabBarView with class items:

```
TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: const [
                    ListaCatTareas(),
                    ListaSubCatTareas(),
                    ListaTiposTareas(),

                  ],
                ),
```

I would like to change the active tabbar index from inside of all the children widgets.

For example, I have selected to open the widget at index 1, which is ListaSubCatTareas,
then inside of this widget I may need to change the tabbar active index to 0 or 2.

Comment: Use a callback inside the widget that triggers a function outside, you can also pass parameters to the function. See this tutorial for more information: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-widget-communication

Comment: @WilsonToribio, thank you, I am already using a callback function that gets a parameter, but  I need to know how to change the active index tab from inside a tab child

Comment: I am very glad to help you. But I do not see that ListaSubCatTareas(), or any other of the child widgets are using a callback, or you did not put it here? An alternative that you can use is to use Provider to change the index from the provider class.

Comment: @WilsonToribio, what do you need to see?

Comment: @WilsonToribio, I will try to use Provider, may be the solution, at least for now.

Comment: Actually when a callback is pass to a widget it is pass like this:  `ListaSubCatTareas(callback: changeindex)`  them you pass what you want to do inside the widget for example: `callback(2)`, but I do not see you are passing it to the widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tabController.index` to change the tab bar active index. check running below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TabBarSampleClass(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarSampleClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabBarSampleClassState createState() => _TabBarSampleClassState();
}

class _TabBarSampleClassState extends State<TabBarSampleClass>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tab Navigation'),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: const <Widget>[
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.book, color: Colors.white),
              text: 'TabOne',
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.chat, color: Colors.white),
              text: 'TabTwo',
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
              text: 'TabThree',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_circle_right,
            ),
            iconSize: 50,
            color: Colors.green,
            splashColor: Colors.purple,
            onPressed: () {
              //Navigate to tab 2
              _tabController.index = 1;
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_circle_right,
            ),
            iconSize: 50,
            color: Colors.green,
            splashColor: Colors.purple,
            onPressed: () {
              //Navigate to tab 3
              _tabController.index = 2;
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_circle_right,
            ),
            iconSize: 50,
            color: Colors.green,
            splashColor: Colors.purple,
            onPressed: () {
              //Navigate to tab 1
              _tabController.index = 0;
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

or if you are using CustomWidgetClass, pass the _tabController object to the custom widget and navigate by same `_tabController.index = 2;`

```
CustomClassForThridTab(
 tabcontroller: _tabController
),
```

[image]